# Non English caption reference doesn't print the name

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, labels

When I try to reference caption it only shows the number of the figure without the name. For example it prints *1* instead of *Фигура 1*. I am using babel and typing in Bulgarian. Is this some kind of bug because its not English text and how can I fix it? This is my preambule:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english,bulgarian]{babel} 
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgf} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
```

This is the figure:

```
\begin{figure}
             \centering
             \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
                 \clip(-0.38,-0.44) rectangle (3.25,5.2);
                 \draw [shift={(0,0)},fill=black,fill opacity=0.1] (0,0) -- (0:0.6) arc (0:61.07:0.6) -- cycle;
                 \draw (0,0)-- (2.68,0);
                 \draw (2.68,4.85)-- (2.68,0);
                 \draw (2.68,4.85)-- (0,0);
                 \begin{scriptsize}
                     \fill [color=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
                     \draw[color=black] (0.17,0.26) node {$A$};
                     \fill [color=black] (2.68,0) circle (1.5pt);
                     \draw[color=black] (2.83,0.26) node {$B$};
                     \draw[color=black] (1.41,-0.18) node {$a$};
                     \fill [color=black] (2.68,4.85) circle (1.5pt);
                     \draw[color=black] (2.83,5.1) node {$C$};
                     \draw[color=black] (2.43,2.57) node {$b$};
                     \draw[color=black] (1.11,2.73) node {$c$};
                     \draw[color=black] (0.61,0.22) node {$\alpha$};
                     \fill [color=black] (1.34,2.42) circle (1.5pt);
                     \draw[color=black] (1.51,2.69) node {$D$};
                 \end{scriptsize}
             \end{tikzpicture} \caption{}\label{fig:triangle}
\end{figure}
```

And this is how I reference the caption:

```
 Нека тази точка бъде средата на
 хипотенузата на правоъгълен триъгълник,
 точка $D$ от \ref{fig:triangle}
```

This doesn't work either:

```
\end{tikzpicture} \caption{\label{fig:triangle}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is normal: `\ref{fig:triangle}` only prints the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not depend on the language: `\ref` only prints the number.

Either you add Фигура yourself, or you use a higher level package such as `cleveref`. However, this package lacks support for Bulgarian, so you need to teach it the names associated to the counters.

The text for the first option should be

```
Нека тази точка бъде средата на
хипотенузата на правоъгълен триъгълник,
точка $D$ от Фигура~\ref{fig:triangle}
```

With `cleveref` it can be like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english,bulgarian]{babel} 
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgf} 
\usepackage{caption} 

\usepackage{cleveref} % after hyperref if you use it

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\crefname{figure}{Фигура}{Фигури} % singular and plural

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\scriptsize
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
  \clip(-0.38,-0.44) rectangle (3.25,5.2);
  \draw [shift={(0,0)},fill=black,fill opacity=0.1] (0,0) -- (0:0.6) arc (0:61.07:0.6) -- cycle;
  \draw (0,0)-- (2.68,0);
  \draw (2.68,4.85)-- (2.68,0);
  \draw (2.68,4.85)-- (0,0);
  \fill [color=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
  \draw[color=black] (0.17,0.26) node {$A$};
  \fill [color=black] (2.68,0) circle (1.5pt);
  \draw[color=black] (2.83,0.26) node {$B$};
  \draw[color=black] (1.41,-0.18) node {$a$};
  \fill [color=black] (2.68,4.85) circle (1.5pt);
  \draw[color=black] (2.83,5.1) node {$C$};
  \draw[color=black] (2.43,2.57) node {$b$};
  \draw[color=black] (1.11,2.73) node {$c$};
  \draw[color=black] (0.61,0.22) node {$\alpha$};
  \fill [color=black] (1.34,2.42) circle (1.5pt);
  \draw[color=black] (1.51,2.69) node {$D$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{}\label{fig:triangle}

\end{figure}

Нека тази точка бъде средата на
хипотенузата на правоъгълен триъгълник,
точка $D$ от \cref{fig:triangle}

\end{document}
```

[image]