# tableofcontents, chapter, etc. showing up in weird font

Tags: table-of-contents, babel, font-encodings

**PROBLEM SOLVED, SEE EDITS 2 AND 3.**

so i have several files written in bulgarian that are set up to compile into one PDF
however in the process of doing so, several errors popped up despite me compiling the files individually before with no issue whatsoever

first of all, when using \tableofcontents the file wounldn't build and texstudio would return errors like this instead

`Command \CYRO unavailable in encoding OT1. ...C {\cyre }\IeC {\cyrm }\IeC {\cyri } }{7}{}`
problem is i'm not even using encoding OT1, but T2A and X2.
removing talbeofcontents let the file build successfuly, however that bring us to my second issue

the font on tings like chapters, sections and certain symbols is replaced with this odd font

[image]

copying the text and pasting it somewhere else displays the text as saying "chapter 1" even though the text for everything should be in bulgarian

**EDIT: upon further inspection, all latin characters seem to be affected, but none in cyrillic**

**EDIT 2: swapping the places of bulgarian and english in \usepackage corrected the font for the headers, as they display in bulgarian now and not garbled in any way. latin characters characters still appear to be messed- up though**

**EDIT 3: removing X2 from `\usepackage[T2A, X2]{fontenc}` fixed the problem with the garbled english font.**

the packages i'm using are the following

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage[T2A, X2]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}

\usepackage[bulgarian, english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A, X2]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,bulgarian]{babel}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with texstudio. You should remove that from the title.

Comment: alright then, sorry

Comment: What is the input for TOC line you show?

Comment: i can'y say I had any input for that line, all i did was write \tableofcontents

Comment: The odd string you show is, I'm pretty sure, just a substitution of the glyphs in the Cyrillic font in the positions for "Chapter", but since it's not clear what font is being used, I can't check it.  However, and probably not relevant, several packages are being loaded multiple times: `inputenc`, `fontenc`, `babel`, `amsfonts` (loaded by `amssymb`).  The order of `fontenc` and `inputenc` may be important; I'm not sure where to check that.

Comment: i tried reverse searching the font using font identification websites, but came back empty- handed. the font seems to be a mixture of cyrillic and english, that's for sure.
anyway, i removed the repeating lines and swapped the order of fontenc and inputenc, but that didn't seem to work

Comment: `fontenc` and `inputenc` are old-style method for legacy fonts, not really needed these days, especially with Unicode fonts. Are you able to save the .tex file as utf-8, not cp1251? Code page 1251 is for Cyrillic 8-bit fonts (from before Unicode) and overlaps with latin. Can you use Noto Serif font (with `fontspec`), for output? (Or some other ttf/otf font with Cyrillic characters).

Comment: Maybe related: For legacy fonts, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204224/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-supported-fonts-in-bulgarian-along-with-examples
For captions with babel, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312296/non-english-caption-reference-doesnt-print-the-name
do not use `fontenc` and `inputenc`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153554/command-maketitle-with-cyrillic-and-times-new-roman

Comment: right, following the instructions on the last link you posted gives me the error
```Error: Command crashed: xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "FILE-2022".tex``` 
i also used xelatex to compile it.

Comment: also i managed to fix one of the problems (see edit 2)

Comment: i'm really, really, really sorry for spamming this thread so much and wasting everyone's time, but i managed to correct my issue (see edit 3)